# Calling a grandparent JS function that includes jquery from a nested iFrame. D7

Tags: javascript

I'm calling the grandparent_func from a second-level nested iframe like so.
This works in a non-Drupal environment, but am getting the following errors when running in drupal. (yes. I did remember to include the jquery file ;-)

```
parent.parent.grandparent_func( Date.now(), Date.now());
```

ERRORS:

For the following, I get a "TypeError: $ is not a function" error

```
<script>
    function grandparent_func(){        
        $("#fancy_regit_link").attr("href", "/my/actual/path");
        $("#fancy_regit_link").trigger('click');                

    }
</script>
```

So, I enclosed jquery like so to make it drupal-friendly and get:
TypeError: parent.grandparent_func is not a function

```
<script>
(function($) {
    function grandparent_func(){        
        $("#fancy_regit_link").attr("href", "/my/actual/path");
        $("#fancy_regit_link").trigger('click');                

    }
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

For good measure, I double enclose it with jquery's ready function.
TypeError: parent.grandparent_func is not a function

```
<script>
(function($) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        function grandparent_func(){        
            $("#fancy_regit_link").attr("href", "/my/actual/path");
            $("#fancy_regit_link").trigger('click');                

        }
    }); 
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introducing a closure around the whole function (as in your 2nd and 3rd examples) will take it out of the global scope, so it won't be available on the `window`, and subsequently the iframe's `parent` (which are the same thing).

What you're looking for is more like:

```
function grandparent_func() {        
  (function($) {
    $("#fancy_regit_link").attr("href", "/my/actual/path");
    $("#fancy_regit_link").trigger('click');                
  })(jQuery);
}
```

That makes sure `grandparent_func` is global, while still providing you the jQuery object.

Comment: This worked beautifully, Clive. Thanks. I have a feeling I'm going to be putting these all over the place now. This probably will create havoc when I take it back out of drupal. By chance, Do you know if there's a quick way to make that wrapper NOT a problem. I don't really understand what it's doing. Thanks again.

Comment: No need to worry, that's nothing to do with Drupal as such it's a simple [anonymous function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140089/how-does-an-anonymous-function-in-javascript-work). It'll work the same outside of Drupal as it does inside, your code won't need to change